# Google Maps API v3 inside another Div

Tags: css, google-maps, html

This is a drop down Div - which works with everything except GoogleMap.

I get half the map showing or maybe a 1/4 of it... When I get rid of the div's all works fine... Or is there a workaround without div's? Ideas... I tried declaring table, p etc... No luck...

Javascript Drop Down Code and Div calls

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function showElement(layer){
   var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
   if(myLayer.style.display=="none"){
   myLayer.style.display="block";
   myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";
   } else { 
   myLayer.style.display="none";
   }
   }
   </script>

  <div class=catlist>
  <table border=0 cellpadding=4>
  <tr>
  <td valign=middle><img src="images/plus.png" onclick="javascript:showElement('ed')"></td>
  <td valign=middle><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showElement('ed')"><b>Edit GPS 
  Map</b></a></td>
  </tr></table>
  </div>
  <div class="qlist" id="ed" style="display:none;">

  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>

  </div>
```

---

### Adding the Google Javascript...

This is the actual Google Maps Javascript...
Cold Fusion Plots the # markers...
This works fine outside of divs...
Code suggested above works to display the correct map interface...
But the centering of the plot is not working...
And marker shows at top left corner with above code provided...

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
  </script> 

  <script type="text/javascript"> 

  var locations = [ 
["#bsname#", #gpslat#, #gpslong#, #busid#], 
  ]; 

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
  zoom: 15, 
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(#gpslat#, #gpslong#), 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }); 

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

  var marker, i; 

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {   
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
    map: map 
  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
    return function() { 
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); 
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    } 
  })(marker, i)); 
  } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changes I made were:

- triggering a resize when the div is expanded
- centering the map after the resize
- making map and locations variables global.

The jsfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp9z/9

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var map;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

// CHANGED locations and map now global so they refer to the same thing in both initialize and showElement

var locations = [ 
["a", 40.2, -88.8, "k"], 
  ]; 

var map;

function initialize() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
  // CHANGED
      zoom: 10, 
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2, -88.8), 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }); 

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

  var marker, i; 

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {   
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
    map: map 
  }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
    return function() { 
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]); 
      infowindow.open(map, marker); 
    } 
  })(marker, i)); 
  } 

      }
function showElement(layer){
   var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
   if(myLayer.style.display=="none"){
   myLayer.style.display="block";
   myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";

   // *** add the trigger here ***
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   var mylat=locations[0][1];
   var mylng=locations[0][2];
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mylat,mylng));

   } else { 
   myLayer.style.display="none";
   }
}

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class=catlist>
  <table border=0 cellpadding=4>
  <tr>
Lat:   <input type="text" id="mylat" value="40.2">
Lng:   <input type="text" id="mylng" value="-88.8">
      <!-- <td valign=middle><img src="images/plus.png" onclick="javascript:showElement('ed')"></td> -->
  <td valign=middle><a href="#" onclick="javascript:showElement('ed')"><b>Edit GPS 
  Map</b></a></td>
  </tr></table>
  </div>
  <div class="qlist" id="ed" style="display:none;">

  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making the map resize after you show the div should work:

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference): "Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size:" `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') .`

**EDIT** - I'll be more specific, please try again

```
function showElement(layer){
   var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
   if(myLayer.style.display=="none"){
   myLayer.style.display="block";
   myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";

   // *** add the trigger here ***
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

   } else { 
   myLayer.style.display="none";
   }
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp9z/

Comment: Tried it... Added the above to the Map Javascript... Still cuts off half the map...

Comment: Please try again, this time I showed where to make the change

Comment: k close - but when google maps centers - the actual plot of the location is in top left corner - not centered... Will add the google map javascript

Comment: Added the Google Javasricpt - get center marker not centering - pops into top left corner...

Comment: I wasn't aware of centering, you should put the map.setCenter after the resize trigger. Otherwise the first time you open the map it will be off. http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp9z/5/ Also, you cannot name javascript variables starting with #. $name$ is ok, however.

Comment: No luck... As the trigger call only works in the non google map javascript

Comment: The # variables are cold fusion dumps... #gpslat# for example - becomes 51.234 when processed in cold fusion...

Comment: OK, I made another update. http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp9z/9/ A crucial change I made was setting locations and map global (defined outside of their functions) so both functions can access the same thing. Is this the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Excellent - yep works... This is correct Javascript here - http://jsfiddle.net/Mgp9z/9/  I'm still learning this Java stuff - Mia - post new code as correct answer and I'll check it as answer for u...